# Understanding how ProgressDialog works

Tags: android, progressdialog

I work with a Device with fix API 23 and because I thought it would be easy I wanted to use ProgressDialog since it is still available.

I tried to start a Thread which needs to do a lot of work and while he is doing this the user has to wait.

I got different issues while using the ProgressDialog:

## 1. Doesn't stop

```java
public void buttun(View view) {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);
        addCustomQueue.start();
        getCustomQueue.start();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

In this case with the button click the ProgressDialog shows up but `.dismiss()` doesn't work. (I know that the ProgessDialog should close immediately even when the Thread is not finished. I just wanted to know if  `.dismiss()` works.)

## 2. To much work on MainThread

```java
public void buttun(View view) {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);
        addCustomQueue.start();
        getCustomQueue.start();

        try {
            addCustomQueue.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

When I try to `.join()` one Thread which will surely end after 20 sec, the ProgressDialog shows up after about 30s and also  `.dismiss()` doesn't work. But I got the information about the thread being finished.

The Style I want to use is the second one, but I need a proper way to do it.
What is the right way to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Doesn't stop

In fact, `ProgressDialog.show(Context, String, String, boolean)` is a static method, it creates a new ProgressDialog and return it after showing it.

You should change your code like this.

```java
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

## 2. Too much work on MainThread

You should **never** block Android's [MainThread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads), so join a thread on MainThread is not a good idea.

Instead of joining a long-running thread on MainThread, you can use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#Handler) to post callbacks on MainThread.

Your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private AddCustomQueueThread addCustomQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addCustomQueue = new AddCustomQueueThread(this);
    }

    public void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if(mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    public void button(View view) {
        addCustomQueue.start();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);
    }
}
```

Your Thread:

```
    class AddCustomQueueThread extends Thread {
        final WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;
        final Handler handler;
        AddCustomQueueThread(MainActivity act) {
            activity = new WeakReference<>(act);
            handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            //do your work.

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity act = activity.get();
                    if(act != null) {
                        act.dismissProgressDialog();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Please note: we are storing reference to activity inside a WeakReference, this is needed to prevent leaking of your activity.

Comment: This is the correct and complete answer. Thanks, of course it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two `Progressdialog` objects.

```
//Instead of 
//ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//mProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);

//use
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Title","Message",true);

//Now, you'll be able to dismiss it
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

It isn't the most intuitive of methods, but the static `show(..)` methods create and display a progressdialog. ([Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean)))

> `static ProgressDialog
>   show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate)`
>
> Creates and shows a ProgressDialog.

P.S - Reyhane's answer should also work, since the `show()` method is an object level method that directly shows the dialog instead of creating one and showing. ([Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()))

Comment: So what I did was creating two ProgressDialogs and I was trying to `.dismiss()` the one I never Initialized?

Comment: You created two dialogs, opened the second, and kept trying to close the first (instead of the second).

Comment: I see. Thanks, I will try this out directly. Have a nice day.

Comment: Cool, mark my answer as correct if it works. Cheers.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the answer of @ZumiKua is completely facing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  Here you can do your background task for processing data that may take seconds
            addCustomQueue.start();
            getCustomQueue.start();
            try {
                addCustomQueue.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Here you can put code for UI changes that display on screen
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

You can mange it by proper multi threding performance here i provide you example only because of i dont know you functionality and your code.

Comment: The Threads `addCustomQueue` and `getCostumQueue` are extended by Thread. So they should run on a background thread.
I don't need to do `runOnUiThread` because I allready start the ProgressDialog on MainThread.

Comment: So what is an issue you are facing mainly you have not to mention properly or update your question

Answer (score 0):

You should write below code before start your works :

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pd.setMessage("Processing...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
```

and after end works write this:
`pd.cancel();`